# Does shapechanging come under Entitlement(Shapechange), the Vessel power or can it be either?

Tags: part-time-gods

I'm a bit confused in part time gods about changing shapes. There are a few powers under the shaping manifestation skill that allow for this. But on the other hand there exists an animal form entitlement (some npcs have a shapechangingpower like dragons which looks more like an entitlement).

Sooo if I have a godling that can take on other forms for example the forms of people he met, or a dragons form would that be an entitlement (shapechange) or would that fall under the "Vessel" power of the shaping manifestation skill or could it be done both ways?
(as a note there: Tehre is no need to gain additional abilities like claws that can cut through things. It's just optical shapechanging)

*Related question in terms of the main confusion about shape changing powers: [Does beast form entitlement include just mundane animals, or can you also change into things like dragons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59118/part-time-gods-beast-form-entitlement)*