# Does beast form entitlement include just mundane animals, or can you also change into things like dragons?

Tags: part-time-gods

Does beast form entitlement only include mundane animals like cats, or also things like dragons?

If so, does it only give basic powers like turning you into a human sized dragon (if you don't also have the colossal entitlement) or does it do more for you there?

Comment: **Before answering this question, notice that the tags are for the *Part-Time Gods* RPG, not *Dungeons & Dragons*.** The mods would prefer to avoid needing to delete any more answers about D&D.

Answer (score 1):

If it falls under beast, then a magical beast, enchantment beast, beast, dark beast, whatever that has beast, is acceptable. The size should be noted, however. Colossal entitlement is prolly the only way you can get away with things bigger than yourself, or not much bigger, like a cow. And since you're Gm, whatever you want goes to some degree.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at it, it states the following "The god may turn into an animal of their choosing." Since this is quite broad of a answer I would suggest you ask your GM or if you are the GM think before you say yes. Dragons are Mythological Beasts not Mythological Animals. But either way, the way it is worded means that yes you can pick a dragon. But pass it by your GM first!

Comment: I AM the GM and I'm not sure on how the rules can be interpreted. In regards to mythological beasts that is.

Comment: @ThomasE. You can give the guy the Dragon but allow it to only be his size unless as you stated he has the "colossal entitlement" But it's mainly down to your opinion as a GM.

Comment: And that is the thing and also what my question is about. Does the non houseruled power allow for this all?

Comment: @ThomasE. For all purposes I would say no since dragons in mythology are always these large to gigantic creatures. But if the had colossal entitlement before they got beast form I would say yes.

Comment: @Pallas You should edit your answer to provide rules guidance.